# Filter model, then join with many-to-many relation

Tags: laravel, filter, many-to-many, eloquent

I have two models, `User` and `Training`. They have many-to-many relationship with additional pivot fields like `is_speaker` and `is_creator`. I want to:

1. Get all the users with specified column value, for example: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE business_unit = Finance`;
2. Get the associated `training`s where the pivot column value is `is_speaker = true`;

In other words, a visitor searches for all the trainings whose (first) speaker belongs to the specified business unit.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$bu_users = $this->user->where( 'business_unit', $business_unit )->get();
$speakerTrainings = $bu_users->trainings()->wherePivot( 'is_speaker', true )->get();
dd( $speakerTrainings );
// Returns: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `trainings` where (select count(*) from `users` inner join `training_user` on `users`.`id` = `training_user`.`user_id` where `training_user`.`training_id` = `trainings`.`id` and `business_unit` = Finance and `users`.`is_active` = 1) >= 1 and `pivot` = is_speaker)
```

.

```
$bu_trainings = $this->training->with( 'users' )
    ->where( 'business_unit', '=', $business_unit )
    ->wherePivot( 'is_speaker', true)
    ->get();
dd( $bu_trainings );
// Returns: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'business_unit' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `trainings` where `business_unit` = Finance and `pivot` = is_speaker)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Now we kind of need to mix the two queries you have and add a bit of `whereHas`

Try this (this code returns all the users who belong to the specified business unit and are also speakers on any training):

```
$users = $this->user
         ->whereHas('trainings', function($q){
             $q->where('training_user.is_speaker', true);
         })
         ->where('business_unit', $business_unit)
         ->get();
```

This code will return all the trainings which have at least one speaker from the specified business unit:

```
$trainings = $this->training->whereHas( 'users', function( $q )
{
    $business_unit  = Input::get( 'bu' );
    $q->where( 'training_user.is_speaker', true );
    $q->where( 'business_unit', $business_unit );
})->get;
```

#### Edit

I know this isn't ideal but it's the only thing I can think of that works

First, for ease of use, define a `speakers` relation

```
public function speakers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->wherePivot('is_speaker', true);
}
```

Then first, eager load all speakers, filter the trainings them afterwards (edited):

```
$business_unit = Input::get('bu');
$trainings = $this->training->has('speakers')->with('speakers')->get();
$trainings = $trainings->filter(function($training) use ($business_unit){
    return $training->speakers->sortBy('training_user.id')->first()->business_unit == $business_unit;
});
```

Comment: this isn't quite what I need, but you helped me progress. Your query seems to return all the users who belong to the specified business unit and who are also speakers. I need to return the trainings whose speaker belongs to the business unit. I'll add my edit to your answer.

Comment: Now, I've added what seems to be working for me, but not completely. That code returns all the trainings which have at least one speaker from the specified business unit. I need to only get one speaker per training (ideally something like `->first()`) and check their business unit. Can that be done?

Comment: What if you add `$q->take(1)` inside the `whereHas` closure?

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: You mean that when you do `$training->users` you only want to get one? Or do I understand you wrong?

Comment: Well yes, for example if I do this for one of the resulting trainings: `$training->users()->where( 'training_user.is_speaker', true )->first()->full_name` I get the first speaker for that training. That is the same user whose business unit is relevant for my query, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ah know I know what you mean. That's a tough one... I'll try some things and come back to you if I get to the solution

Comment: Check out my edit. This should work, the code is untested though

Comment: thank you very much for all your time and effort, I really appreciate it. For some reason I'm getting the same result with this one...

Comment: I think I got it. I only modified the content of the filter trait to look like this: `return $training->speakers->sortBy( 'training_user.id' )->first()->business_unit == $business_unit;`. It seems to me that the problem was the first speaker was being returned, but in the alphabetical order. I'm still not 100% sure, but I'll keep testing. Thank you once again lukasgeiter and a happy new year!

Comment: Hmm that kind of suprises me. I would have thought the default sort is by primary key (here `id`) but anyways. As long as it does what it's supposed to ;) A happy new year to you too!